# Spring Hibernate Duplicate Data Saving

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am saving data with AJAX POST call using Spring and Hibernate JPA. Even after a status check the code executes more than once.

[image]

```
Order order1 = orderFacility.get(order.getId());
if (!order1.getOst().equals(APPROVED.getValue())) {
   productFacility.increaseProductInOrderQtyBasedOnCustOrderQty(order,
         CARE_PAGE_CUSTORDER_STATUS_CHANGE.toString() + ": "
         + order.getStatus().toUpperCase() + " -> " + OrderStatus.getByValue(st));
   order.setOst(APPROVED.getValue());
   orderFacility.save(order);
 }
```

From the attached image you can see the Green Bordered row which is OK. But, the Red Bordered rows are duplicates. From the Entry Time you can have an idea. Please suggest me to stop these duplicates.

What I did so far:

1. Hide button after the AJAX call, so user can’t click the button twice
2. Checked status if the entry already updated, if updated, then do not update again.

Comment: based your approach, when you do a request from postman as client to spring boot api, does it work? or do you think that the problem is when front-end?

Comment: Moreover... may you post some piece of code?

Comment: @AngeloImmediata code added.

Comment: I guess it's something related to the JPA mapping entities. May you post also involved entities?

Comment: @AngeloImmediata I do not think it is related with entities. The if() condition is not working.

Comment: I don’t know. Did you put a breakpoint there? May it be related to a double post on client side? For example in Joubert if you don’t stop event propagation sometimes double submits are executed

Comment: @AngeloImmediata Yes, used breakpoint. The problem is, I can not generate the scenario locally even sending multiple request using postman.

Comment: Well if by using postman all works good I’d investigate on the client side by debugging the web source code

Comment: @JonathanJohx can not generate using postman. I disabled the button from front-end after first click.

Comment: Looks a front-end issue, if the action on button save does several things, I suggest you use promise JIC.